# Show 4 videos simultaneously

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a problem with VideoView. I want to show 4 videos simultaneously. And only one of them working.(pistol) The other does not appear.
I use this code for videos:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.****_layout, container, false);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());

        VideoView videopistol = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_ability_pistol);
        Uri pistol = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.****.****/raw/video_ability_pistol");
        videopistol.setVideoURI(pistol);
        videopistol.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videopistol);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videopistol);

        VideoView videoblink = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_ability_blink);
        Uri blink = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.****.****/raw/video_ability_blink");
        videoblink.setVideoURI(blink);
        videoblink.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoblink);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoblink);


        VideoView videorecall = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_ability_recall);
        Uri recall = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.****.****/raw/video_ability_recall");
        videorecall.setVideoURI(recall);
        videorecall.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videorecall);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videorecall);


        VideoView videopulse = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_ability_pulse_bomb);
        Uri pulse = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.****.****/raw/video_ability_pulse_bomb");
        videopulse.setVideoURI(pulse);
        videopulse.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videopulse);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videopulse);

        videopistol.start();
        videoblink.start();
        videorecall.start();
        videopulse.start();

        return view;
    }
```

and XML file

```
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/video_ability_pistol"/>
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/video_ability_blink"/>
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/video_ability_recall"/>
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/video_ability_pusle_bomb"/>
```

Someone can help me ? I don't find the problem.

Comment: First, I am not aware that you can have multiple `VideoView` widgets working in the same activity. Second, `MediaController` can only work with one `VideoView` at a time.

Comment: So how can i do ? I want 4 video. And the user play the video he wants.

Comment: It sounds like you do not "want 4 video". It sounds like you want one video -- the one the user wants to play. The other three can be static images, until such time as the user indicates that the user wants to switch to a different video. In that case, use one `VideoView` and three `ImageView` widgets, populating the `ImageView` widgets with thumbnails from the videos.

Comment: That is exactly whats I want. But I'm a novice in android programming. I don't know how to do that.
Can you explain in more detail?